# Is WebSocket Stateful?

Tags: http, https, websocket, state

I've heard confusing things about statefulness and HTTP.  Is WebSocket stateful?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, WebSocket is stateful.

It uses the "Sec-WebSocket-Key" HTTP header to establish and maintain state between server and client.

[You can read more about it on its RFC.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.2)